# Shared Lock issued on IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, locking, isolation-level

I read that if I use IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted, the query should not issue any locks. However, when I tested this, I saw the following lock:

> Resource_Type: HOBT
>   Request_Mode: S (Shared)

What is a HOBT lock? Something related to HBT (Heap or Binary Tree lock)?

Why would I still get a S lock?

How do I avoid shared locking when querying without turning on the isolation level snapshot option?

I am testing this on SQLServer 2008, and the snapshot option is set to off. The query only performs a select.

I can see that Sch-S is required, although SQL Server seems not to be showing it in my lock query. How come it still issues a Shared Lock?  According to:

[SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)

> Transactions running at the `READ UNCOMMITTED` level do not issue shared locks to prevent other transactions from modifying data read by the current transaction.

So I am a little confused.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> What is HOBT lock?

[A lock protecting a B-tree (index) or the heap data pages in a table that does not have a clustered index.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189849.aspx)

> Why would I still get a S lock?

This happens on heaps. Example

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Query nvarchar(max) = 
   N'DECLARE @C INT; 
     SELECT @C = COUNT(*) FROM master.dbo.MSreplication_options';

/*Run once so compilation out of the way*/
EXEC(@Query);

DBCC TRACEON(-1,3604,1200) WITH NO_INFOMSGS;

PRINT 'READ UNCOMMITTED';
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
EXEC(@Query);

PRINT 'READ COMMITTED';
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
EXEC(@Query);

DBCC TRACEOFF(-1,3604,1200) WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
```

**Output `READ UNCOMMITTED`**

```
Process 56 acquiring Sch-S lock on OBJECT: 1:1163151189:0  (class bit0 ref1) result: OK

Process 56 acquiring S lock on HOBT: 1:72057594038910976 [BULK_OPERATION] (class bit0 ref1) result: OK

Process 56 releasing lock on OBJECT: 1:1163151189:0
```

**Output `READ COMMITTED`**

```
Process 56 acquiring IS lock on OBJECT: 1:1163151189:0  (class bit0 ref1) result: OK

Process 56 acquiring IS lock on PAGE: 1:1:169 (class bit0 ref1) result: OK

Process 56 releasing lock on PAGE: 1:1:169

Process 56 releasing lock on OBJECT: 1:1163151189:0
```

According to [this article](http://tenbulls.co.uk/2011/10/14/nolock-hits-mythbusters/) referencing Paul Randal the reason for taking this `BULK_OPERATION` shared HOBT lock is to prevent reading of unformatted pages.

Answer (score 7):

ReadUncommitted isolation level does acquire locks. Schema stability locks prevent the objects being queried from being altered while the query executes. These locks are acquired under all isolation leveles, including snapshot and read_committed_snapshot (RCSI). From [Lock Modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519.aspx):

> Schema Locks
>
> The Database Engine uses schema modification (Sch-M) locks during a
> table data definition language (DDL) operation, such as adding a
> column or dropping a table. During the time that it is held, the Sch-M
> lock prevents concurrent access to the table. This means the Sch-M
> lock blocks all outside operations until the lock is released.
>
> Some data manipulation language (DML) operations, such as table
> truncation, use Sch-M locks to prevent access to affected tables by
> concurrent operations.
>
> The Database Engine uses schema stability (Sch-S) locks when compiling
> and executing queries. Sch-S locks do not block any transactional
> locks, including exclusive (X) locks. Therefore, other transactions,
> including those with X locks on a table, continue to run while a query
> is being compiled. However, concurrent DDL operations, and concurrent
> DML operations that acquire Sch-M locks, cannot be performed on the
> table.